# XCode: App Won't Run on Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to run the app that I am developing on the simulator but it just build the app but don't run it. Testing it on the device is ok.

I tired restarting both XCode and iMac, clean and clean build, but still won't run the app on the simulator.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: If there is any other instance of app installed on the simulator then delete it, clean the project and then run it again.

Comment: Is there something shows on the  debugger area?

Comment: What exactly happens? Do you see any log on XCode console?

Comment: Does a simple HelloWorld can run?

Comment: as VaibhabGautam said Reset Simulator with open simulator go to menu ->ios Simulator Reset content and settings. than run application it would work.hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: @VaibhavGautam you're right! Post your comment as answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @ChanoTarongoy : posted as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try resetting your simulator. It will work.

from top menu click "Simulator" -> "Reset contents and settings.."

Answer (score 0):

Recently,i find out that if you have modified you /etc/hosts files and change 127.0.0.1 to another domain rather than localhost,XCode will fail to attatch the process on your simulator.

Restore you /etc/hosts file may fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the last answer by RockSuger on here [app runs on device but won't run on simulator](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50084)

1. I checked which version of Xcode I was running. Click: `Xcode > About XCode` My version was `9.2`
2. In the project navigator I went to the blue project icon in the top of the upper left corner, clicked `Deployment Info > Deployment Target` and changed the old target from 9.1 to `9.2`